# How to download genetic/SNP data from UK Biobank

Tags: bioinformatics

For an approved research project, how to download the genetic/SNP data? The tabular data (demographics and clinical) has already been downloaded successfully, but the documentation does not really show how to download the corresponding SNP data. Any directions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation regarding that from the UKB in the questions 10-15 in the FAQ on that link to I think explain the process: (https://www.ukbiobank.ac.uk/media/cffi4mx5/ukb-genotyping-and-imputation-data-release-faq-v3-2-1.pdf)

In the table in the site below, I see some SNP data is available from UKB directly. I guess it depends what SNP data they are after: https://biobank.ctsu.ox.ac.uk/crystal/crystal/docs/ukbgene_instruct.html

I hope it helps to start!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be well-documented [here](https://biobank.ctsu.ox.ac.uk/crystal/ukb/docs/instruct_gfetch.html). Using `gfetch`, genotype data can be downloaded in PLINK binary format (`.bed`). Then it can be imported into `R` using packages such as [genio](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/genio/index.html) and [BEDMatrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BEDMatrix/index.html).